# Worklight Foundation 6.2 Server - Access MSPN using proxy

Tags: proxy, push-notification, windows-phone, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to configure push notifications for Windows phone in a `WL 6.2 runtime` server.

We would prefer to use a proxy for accessing the `MSPN service`, instead of giving direct access with specific firewall rules.
Is this a supported configuration ?

I found in infocenter two set of properties for configuring proxy access to Androd and Apple push notification services (`push.gcm.proxy.*` and `push.apns.proxy.*` respectively), but I could not find anything like that for Windows devices.
Is there any equivalent set of properties that might not be documented in infocenter ?

Answer (score 1):

Proxy server support for Push notifications exist only for GCM and APNS notifications. For MPNS or WNS this feature is not yet available.

You can submit a Request for Enhancement [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/).